# Jenkins container docker push error failed to response

Tags: docker, jenkins

I ran Jenkins in Docker container with image jenkins:latest. Plugin docker-build-step was installed. Docker build procedure looks good but something goes wrong when it did docker push: [docker push error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBzkx.jpg)

Docker Builder was configured in the System Configuration as below:

[Docker Builder Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vyAGX.jpg)

the IP 172.17.0.1 is the host IP address from the jenkins container's view. docker build works but docker push failed is something really confused me.

Is there something wrong with my configuration or comprehension? Thank your!

Comment: Are you trying to push in local registry or any cloud hosted registry like `docker.io` or `aws` ?

Comment: Yep, it's a local registry, exactly on the same host with the jenkins container. @chintanthakar

Comment: I suggest you first `curl http://$ip_address:5043/v2` check the output because if you are using local insecure registry you have to mention registry details in `$HOME/.docker/config.json`

Comment: I do could push image to the registry on the host, but can't in Jenkins container. @chintanthakar

Comment: Have you configured `$DOCKER_OPTS= --insecure http://$your_registry_URL` in jenkins container?

Comment: there is no docker in my Jenkins container, neither as file /etc/sysconfig/docker. I think DOCKER_OPTS configured on host is enough, because Jenkins container call host Docker-cli to do the works. @chintanthakar

Comment: are you able to `curl http://$your_registry_URL` from jenkins container ?? as like you use from your host machine the same ip address you have to use in jenkins container

Comment: I tried curl with registry container IP, it looks good. but it goes wrong if I curl the domain img.reg.3g(private domain name), I have no privilege in the Jenkins container so I can't add img.reg.3g resolution sadly.

Comment: Yes that's the point you have to made host entry in your `/etc/hosts` file inside jenkins container.